# Images in comments?

Tags: support, comments

I have seen people post comments with links to images on Stack Exchange's [very own Imgur installation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/).  How can you upload an image for a comment like this?

Comment: I just upload it in an answer section then copy the URL into the comment :P

Comment: @gandalf3  I thought about doing that, but I was wondering if you had a less Mickey-Mousey way.  I guess not :)

Comment: You can also upload the image to the chatroom and copy that link.

Answer (score -1):

**Quote from [GiantCowFilms](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/users/3127/giantcowfilms) : Using external sites can cause a lot of broken images, which is really really bad. The default imgur installation should always be used unless there is a VERY good reason not to.**

Steps you can follow...

1. Prepare your images
2. Safe them on your desktop ...
3. Click the icon that has a mountain and a sun on the text input tool bar
4. Click on the big blue box that says "Drag and drop or Click here".
5. Navigate to the image on the desktop and click "Open"
6. Click on the "Add Picture" button.

[image]
[image]

You can also use **http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/** to share your .blend files in questions.

> **DO NOT DO THIS**
>
> Use photobucket.com personally. Just copy the uploaded file URL using
> the easy copy URL button on photobucket site and just paste it here,
> using  the little mountain icon that says "image" when your mouse
> hover over  it. I also use mega.co.nz for uploading blend files, mega
> provide a very  clean and easy to operate interface, it's pretty much
> free for the average  user 50GB of space for free.
>
> It's pretty easy to do. Image is a great way to show others what you
> are talking about!

Comment: Using external sites can cause a lot of broken images, which is really really bad. The default imgur installation should always be used unless there is a VERY good reason not to.

Comment: Ok I will give that a try. I have always the impression that forums don't want to manage user's images and would rather have a external site handle the load.

Comment: @hawkenfox, what you wrote is true on forums, but stack exchange is not a forum  and has different considerations.

Comment: I would often comeback later to delete unecessary comments. I use it as friendly way to say "I have got the message and I am willing to comply".