# Can you add files to comments?

Tags: support

Is it possible to add .blend files or images to comments? I'm having a bit of difficulty with somebody's answer to my question, and I'd like to give them my .blend file or a screenshot to help them help me out.

Comment: If the screenshot is related more to the question than to the answers or if the screenshot will help other users answer your question, then I think editing the question and adding the image is the best thing to do. Same goes for blend files. Otherwise, use any of the available markdown editors to upload the image to imgur, get the link and add it to the comment using `[Text](Image Link)`.

Comment: Related: https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/985/599

Comment: Instead of using comments, or links in a comment, please edit the original question with all pertinent information, updates and things that you've tried. Comments are oftentimes overlooked and you might not be able to convey the information you want.